# Add tags to a pdf file java

Tags: java, pdf, tags

Is there any way to programatically convert a pdf file into a tagged pdf file? If I try to tag it using Adobe Reader it works, so the pdf can be tagged.

Comment: Well Adobe Reader is a program, so if it can do it, it does it programmatically.

Comment: The tags you are probably talking about are actually a feature by Adobe and not part of the PDF-Standard. Therefore as long as Adobe does not offer an API for those (and I don't know about one) you can probably not do that easily.

Comment: @Ben there doesn't seem to be anything so sinister about PDF tags. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a library that supported it.

Comment: @Kayaman if it is, I should have found it after weeks of searching.

Comment: @Kayaman I thought so, too but I really don't see anything that comes close to it. And maybe I am wrong but I really think tags are not part of the pdf-standard. The only tags the standard talks about are the `<h>` etc. tags for style-formatting.

Comment: There is the Adobe Acrobat SDK out there, which probably also supports this (didn't test) but that's a cpp library as far as I can assess that.

Comment: @Ben the tags seem to be [in the standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Logical_structure_and_accessibility) since a few years. Nothing proprietary about it (well, nothing more proprietary than what PDF already is).

Comment: @Kayaman Oh! That went right past me... for 6 years already... Thanks for the heads-up. Then yes, it should be somehow possible.

Comment: Two weeks of searching and nothing, you need to step up your Google game Alexandra.

Comment: What you are looking for is a library that supports "marked content" and "structure". iText, PDFBox, and Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit are the 3 that I know of that support this. However, unlike Acrobat, you won't be able to just tell the library to tag the document, you'll need to discover what drawing operators create a paragraph, sentence, word, caption to an image, etc. You'd then need to insert the marked content into those instructions. This will be non-trivial using just a library.

Answer (score 0):

Support for tagging is present at least in [iText](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-generate-pdfua-compatible-pdf-itext) which isn't surprising since it's one of the most advanced PDF libraries.

Starting point would be [PdfWriter.setTagged()](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#setTagged--).